# SOQL Selecting CollaborationGroups, GroupMembers and Posts/Comments?

Tags: soql, soap-api

Hey guys I'm trying to take a member, and select the group(s) the belong to, the (other) members in that group, and all posts and comments that are in that group. I have it set right now where I am using two queries to accomplish this, but the first query is not keying off a user id so it is not correct, I would LIKE to be able to merge these two queries into one, but if not possible, just fix the first query so `WHERE MemberId = '{/TheId}'` is fine.

**EDIT**

I almost got it, I'm still relying on another query to get all FeedComments, but I have this here that does almost everything (by User Id). All it needs is to get the `Users inside those groups`

```
            SELECT 
                MemberId,
                CollaborationGroupId,

                CollaborationGroup.CreatedById, 
                CreatedBy.Name,
                Createdby.Email,

                CollaborationGroup.OwnerId, 
                CollaborationGroup.Owner.Name,
                CollaborationGroup.Owner.Email,

                CollaborationGroup.Id, 
                CollaborationGroup.LastModifiedById, 
                CollaborationGroup.Name, 
                CollaborationGroup.MemberCount, 
                CollaborationGroup.CollaborationType, 
                CollaborationGroup.Description, 
                CollaborationGroup.FullPhotoUrl,   
                CollaborationGroup.InformationTitle, 
                CollaborationGroup.InformationBody, 
                CollaborationGroup.CanHaveGuests, 
                CollaborationGroup.CreatedDate, 
                CollaborationGroup.LastModifiedDate,
                CollaborationGroup.LastFeedModifiedDate

            FROM CollaborationGroupMember c

            WHERE ( 
                    ( MemberId = {$client->identity->id} ) AND ( ( CollaborationGroup.LastModifiedDate > {$time} ) 
                                                            OR ( CollaborationGroup.LastFeedModifiedDate > {$time} ) )
                  ) 

            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```